# Calculate power of FFT Frequency component

Tags: python, audio, numpy, signal-processing, fft

I am trying to calculate the power measured in dB of an FFT frequency component for 48000 samples of audio data with a sample rate of 48000 Hz using numpy. The file I am testing has a full power (0 dB) sine wave of 1000 Hz. I am expecting a result of 0 dB when I calculate the Root Mean Squared value of the energy band with the most energy, however, I get the following:

```
1000.0Hz 41.8387130383 dB
```

Would any one have an explanation as to why I am getting a different result? My code is below.

'data' is a numpy array of 48000 samples with 32 bit precision. As I understand, I need to normalize the fft result by the length of the data sample.

```
p = np.fft.fft(data)
uniquePts = math.ceil(len(data)+1/2.0)
p = p[0:uniquePts]
freqs = np.fft.fftfreq(len(p))
```

normalize the fft result by the length of the data sample

```
p = np.divide(p,float(len(data)))
p = np.abs(p)
p = np.power(p,2)
```

multiply the FFT result by two to account for the fact that we halved the total number elements in the return FFT array

```
if len(data) % 2 > 0:
  p[1:len(p)] = np.multiply(p[1:len(p)], 2)
else:
  p[1:len(p) - 1] = np.multiply(p[1:len(p) -1], 2)
```

At this point, I find the FFT component with the most energy represented by `idx`:

```
data_size=48000 #1 second of audio
idx=np.argmax(np.abs(p)**2) 
rms = math.sqrt(p[idx])
dbRep = 20 * math.log10((1.0 * rms)/data_size)
print abs(freqs[i] * frate), dbRep
```

Comment: What is the range of the values in `data` ?

Comment: 'data' contains 32bit signed integers from a 24 bit wave file whose signed integer values I sign extended. I can derive the proper db representation from the audio file, so I don't think there is a problem with 'data'.

Comment: OK - so what is the numeric range of `data` ? Is it the full range of a 32 bit signed int, i.e. -2e9 to +2e9, or the full range of 24 bit PCM, or what ?

Comment: full range 24 bit PCM, -8388607 to 8388608

Comment: OK - and what is `data_size` ?

Comment: data_size is 48000 or the length of the sample of audio I am analyzing. I left that out so I will edit my comment to reflect that.

Comment: So it looks like you're normalising the FFT output twice ? I think I see the problem now though (actually two problems) - see answer below...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you have two mistakes:

- you're normalising for the FFT length twice
- you're not accounting for the fact that your data is 24 bit integer so there is an implicit scaling factor of 2^23

We can plug in the numbers to see if this hypothesis is consistent with that you're seeing - the error should be:

```
20 * log10(2^23 / 48000) = 44.8 dB
```

which is probably close enough.

So you need to divide your input samples by 2^23 to get them into the range -1.0 to +1.0, and also remove the second normalisation (where you divide by `data_size`).

Comment: So this would be my max scale that I would use to calibrate my calculation?

Comment: Well if you want 0 dB to correspond to a full scale (-1 to +1) signal then yes, you need to convert your integer samples to their fixed point equivalent. Remember though that 0 dB has no meaning on its own - it's a relative measurement, so you need to define what 0 dB means to you.

Comment: Perfect. Great Explanation.